Airflow - Problem running the dag iterations sequentially inside a nested loop
TL;DR
I am using Airflow to run a set of tasks(operators) for each iteration combination inside a nested loop. But instead of iterations running sequentially, all the iterations start executing tasks parallelly.
Detailed problem statement looks something like this

Load the json, that is basically a list of categories.

Where each category has a name and for that category there exists a list of metrics.

Each metric has a schema(which is nothing but a json schema of a big query table) and a field kpi.

Now for each metric of each category I need to do the following tasks sequentially.

create_table in big query.
insert_data_into_tmp, i.e insert data into the newly created table.
bq_to_gcs, copy the data from big query table to gcs.
gcs_to_S3, copy data from gcs to s3.



Lets assume for the given json, outer and inner loop results in 4 iteration combinations. When the dag runs it starts to execute the create_table tasks parallelly for all 4 iterations, followed by insert_data_into_tmp for all iterations so on and so forth.
Where as I expect the dag to run as follows
Iteration 1:(category_1/metric_1): create_table -> insert_data_into_tmp -> bq_to_gcs -> gcs_to_S3(when finished then trigger).
Iteration 2(category_1/metric_2): create_table -> insert_data_into_tmp -> bq_to_gcs -> gcs_to_S3(when finished).
Iteration 3(category_2/metric_3): create_table -> insert_data_into_tmp -> bq_to_gcs -> gcs_to_S3 (when finished)
Iteration 4(category_2/metric_4): create_table -> insert_data_into_tmp -> bq_to_gcs -> gcs_to_S3 and end of the DAG.
For better understanding below is the dummy version of json
{
    "reports": [
        {
            "name": "category_1",
            "metrics": [
                {
                    "period": "day",
                    "schema": "metric_1.json",
                    "kpi": "metric_1"
                },
                {
                    "period": "month",
                    "schema": "metric_2.json",
                    "kpi": "metric_2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "category_2",
            "metrics": [
                {
                    "period": "month",
                    "schema": "metric_3.json",
                    "kpi": "metric_3"
                },
                {
                    "period": "month",
                    "schema": "metric_4.json",
                    "kpi": "metric_4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

And below is the code of my DAG
with DAG(
          dag_id='daily',
          default_args=default_args,
          start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 4, 10)
)  as dag:
    dag.doc_md = doc_md

    # Define start and end tasks
    start_task = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    end_task = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")



    file_path = "config.json"
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print(data)
        
        # Access property using dictionary indexing
    config_data = data['reports']

    for name in config_data:
        category = name['name']
        metrics = name['metrics']
        for metric in metrics:
            schema =metric['schema']
            kpi = metric['kpi']

            with TaskGroup(f'Writing_{kpi}_table') as export:
            
                schema_file_path = "/schema/"+schema
                with open(schema_file_path, 'r') as f:
                    loadedSchema = json.load(f)

                create_table = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
                    task_id=f"create_{kpi}_tmp",
                    dataset_id=DATASET,
                    table_id=f"tmp_{kpi}",
                    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
                    schema_fields=loadedSchema,
                    gcp_conn_id='gcs',
                    exists_ok=True,
                    dag=dag
                )

                insert_data_into_tmp = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
                    task_id=f"insert_into_{kpi}_tmp",
                    configuration={
                            "query": {
                                "query": f""" INSERT INTO {PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET}.tmp_{kpi}
                                SELECT * FROM {PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET}.{kpi}  """,
                                "useLegacySql": False,
                            }
                        },
                    dag=dag
                )

         
                bq_to_gcs = BigQueryToGCSOperator (
                    task_id=f"{kpi}_to_GCS",
                    source_project_dataset_table=f"{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET}.tmp_{kpi}",
                    destination_cloud_storage_uris=[f'gs://test/{kpi}.parquet'],
                    export_format='PARQUET',
                    compression='SNAPPY',
                    gcp_conn_id='gcs',
                    dag=dag
                )

                gcs_to_S3 = GCSToS3Operator (
                    task_id=f"{category}_to_S3",
                    gcs_bucket="test-dev",
                    gcp_conn_id='gcs',
                    dest_aws_conn_id='aws_s3',
                    dest_s3_key =f"s3:test",
                    keep_directory_structure =True ,
                    replace=False,
                    dag=dag
                )

                start_task >> export  >> end_task

P.S I have no issues with the functioning of any of the operator, all the operators when ran for a single category/metric worked fine. It's just that I am unable to make use of nested loop in a way I want. I appreciate your help and thanks for your time.
I tried the above DAG code, the Actual and expected outcome is explained above.
